# Laravel : How to show dependent variable on tab

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have two tables , categories and product.Each category has id and name. Each product has id, name and category id. Now I want to load the data on each tab when a user click on specific category_id.so related product will be shown on each category tab. I have tried but couldn't get the solution.

Category Model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()

    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Product Model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
     public function category()
         {
             return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
         }

}
```

Here is my controllers:

```
public function gettestItem() {
                $categories = Category::with('products')->get();
                return view('products', compact('categories'));
            }
```

Here is the view :

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="content">               
          <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">   
             @foreach ($categories as $category)              
                <li><a href="#{{$category->id}}" data-toggle="tab" >{{$category->name}}</a></li>
             @endforeach
          </ul>

             <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                  @foreach($category->products as $product) 
                  <div class="tab-pane " id="{{$category->id}}">
                      {{$product->name}}
                  </div>  
                  @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </div>     
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::get('/testItem',[
'uses'=>'ItemController@gettestItem',
'as'=>'testItem'
]);
```

if anyone could help me solve the problem will be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to consider reading up on [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships) and how to use the laravel [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined your schema and relations properly then function should be as:

```
public function gettestItem() {
  $categories = Category::with('products')->get();
  return view('products', compact('categories'));
}
```

then you can access product of each category as:

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $category->product; // gives all products corresponding to $category
}
```

And also please read the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships)

**Update**

Your 2nd `foreach` should be as:

```
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
  @foreach($categories as $category)
    <div class="tab-pane" id="{{$category->id}}">
      @foreach($category->products as $product) 
      <div>
          {{$product->name}}
      </div>  
      @endforeach
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

You can also use following  code to get only those `categories` which have corresponding `products`:

```
$categories = Category::has('products')->with('products')->get();
```

Comment: I have changed with the eloquent solution. But couldn't get the solution.Can you see the update Question please?

Comment: Is there any specific error you are getting? And also you can show what you are expecting and what you are getting.

Comment: The Problem is in the category id only one products is showing instead of showing multiple product.